# ProviderError: invalid 1st argument: address address was not string

Tags: solidity, hardhat

I am trying to deploy my contract on the goerli network. Below is my deployProxy.js

```
const { ethers, upgrades } = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  const VendingMachineV1 = await ethers.getContractFactory("VendingMachineV1");
  const proxy = await upgrades.deployProxy(VendingMachineV1, [100]);
  await proxy.waitForDeployment();

  const implementationAddress = await upgrades.erc1967.getImplementationAddress(
    proxy.getAddress()
  );

  console.log("Proxy contract address: " + proxy.getAddress());

  console.log("Implementation contract address: " + implementationAddress);
}

main();
```

However, I am getting an error after i deploy my contract

`const error = new ProviderError( ProviderError: invalid 1st argument: address address was not string`